# Malicious email in Outlook Sent folder, could it be a clickjacking exploit?

Tags: clickjacking, email-attachments

Recently I discovered there are malicious emails (with HTM attachment) in the Sent folder of an @hotmail account to some unknown recipients in (Outlook app in iPad). I immediately proceed to change the password and enabled 2FA to block unauthorized access.

It was found that more than 100 of emails sent within a day and Chrome flagged the HTML attachment contains virus when attempt to download it for inspection. (no harm right if I open it with Notepad?)

The account was definitely abused but I've no idea how the password was leaked and recent login didn't show anything useful. Otherwise, could it be some exploits (e.g. clickjacking) where clicking on random ads which will trigger mass email forwarding?

Comment: Could it be clickjacking? Maybe, but that's a very specific concern without any evidence to confirm it or even consider it as a possibility. As the answer below states, there could be other ways this could be done.

Answer (score 1):

Possible way of how this happened is malicious app on the iPad, maybe the user installed this app from unofficial source or the password has been found on some leaked database, you can check the email in: haveibeenpwned or similar service, another possible way is that the password was bruteforced or someone had physical access to that iPad when nobody was watching and did shady things.